# Pass javascript variable to Codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Is it posible to get a value from a javascript variable and use it into visual basic code without incrusting value on any control.

Comment: It kinda depends on what kind of situation you want to get a javascript variable. Do you want to get it after a button clicked ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access a js-variable from codebehind without any help of a server-control. 
You could redirect the page to itself and pass that value as URL-Parameter(`window.location.href = window.location.href + "?value=test";`). But i assume that this is not what you want because it forces a postback.
So the best way is to use a hiddenfield:

In javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Foo(){
        var hidden=document.getElementById('hidValue');
        hidden.value="test";
    }
</script>
```

On aspx:

```
<Input id="hidValue" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

In code behind

```
Protected hidValue As HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim hiddenValue = hidValue.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if possible (is available) try to assign value in java to **document.cookie = javavalue** and then get it from codebehind var x= document.cookie (either via webbrowser or page)