# Pass data from Javascript to codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dojo

All --
       I have been trying to find a working example of passing data from a Dojo function to an ASP.Net code behind. THe only post I found that at least offers an easy example is this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8639390/1046341)

Comment: What actually you have not understand ? you add the data on a hidden field and do post back - what else ?

Comment: @Aristos maybe he wants to know how to accomplish this feat?

Answer (score 1):

Hidden inputs are how I do it for simple pages.

ASP.Net Markup (simplified):

```
function saveMyData() {
    var myData = resultOfSomeOtherFunction();
    var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
    hiddenInput.value = myData;
}
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Code-Behind:

value = HiddenField1.Value;

When I want to get fancy, I'll post it to an API I write via an AJAX call.