# doPostBack not working properly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am trying to post back on a button click.But unable to get `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`. It is currently always null. Is there any other entries I have to do?

**aspx**

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="GetDet();" Text="Click"/>       

<script type="text/jscript">
    function GetDet() {
      var obj = $('.output');
      var sign = $('.name'); //hidden field                         
      __doPostBack('btn', sign.val());                         
    }
</script>
```

**.cs**

```
string tar = Convert.ToString(Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET"));
string val = Convert.ToString(Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT"));
```

Comment: what is the value of `sign.val()` ?

Comment: string from hidden field(eg:sam)

Comment: Can also maybe explain what you are trying to do... and why you want the __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT?

Comment: See i need only event arg.I want to pass a value from hidden type input to server side

Comment: that's a hack. Why are trying to hack `ASP.NET` intrinsics when there's better ways to achieve that?

Comment: You can use hidden fields per the answer in this article (I used it just today!) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576899/pass-data-from-javascript-to-codebehind

Comment: show your complete aspx markup. This will help us getting the complete picture

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing such a hack. I'd actually recommend you to do things the proper way so you can guarantee scalability because you never know what's gonna happen on the next release of `ASP.NET` and the ASP.NET Team certainly does not endorse these types of hacks, in other words, your hacks might break with a future releases of `ASP.NET`...always strive to avoid them. So, if you want to do a full postback you definitely don't need javascript for this....

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click"/>
```

Then, if you want to post the value of the hidden field simply add the hidden field to the form...

```
<asp:HiddenField  ID="hdfName" runat="server" Value="whatever" />
```

if you want to read the value of the hidden field during the postback...

```
public override void OnLoad(EventArgs args)
{
     var name = hdfName.Value;
}
```

That's how you are supposed to work with ASP.NET the proper way rather than trying to hack its intrinsics

Comment: Yes i know this method.But i want to what is wrong in my dopostback