# Insert variable value from JS using code injection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

in JS I have this code:

```
var trade ="some text";
var id = 12;
var script = "<img src='"+<%=GetImageURL(id, "~/images/default.jpg") %>+"' 

              alt='"+trade+"' width='180' />";
```

I want to call the method `GetImageURL` with my variable id, but I can't, because this variable is from JS.
How call `GetImageURL` with value of `id` from JS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639278/pass-javascript-variable-to-codebehind

Comment: When GetImageURL is executed, the JS is still being emitted by the server (presumably), so it hasn't been parsed by browser and thus doesn't really exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GetImageURL** is server side method. To call it from javascript (which is client side) you should use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use js variable in server side method. You could use fake ID paramter in GetImageURL and then replace it with js variable in javascript. Something like:

```
var trade ="some text";
var id = 12;
var url = '<%=GetImageURL("[FAKEID]", "~/images/default.jpg") %>'.replace("[FAKEID]",id);
var script = "<img src='"+url +"' alt='"+trade+"' width='180' />";
```

If you want to use GUID then you can set Guid.Empty as fake parameter

```
 var trade ="some text";
 var id = 12;
 var url = '<%=GetImageURL(Guid.Empty, "~/images/default.jpg") %>'.replace("<%=Guid.Empty.ToString()%>",id);
 var script = "<img src='"+url +"' alt='"+trade+"' width='180' />";
```

Comment: "[FAKEID]" is string, but I need to be Guid, have any suggestions how to proceed? please

Comment: I tried to use your code, but when is call the method GetImageURL is sent guid null is not sent id from replace, and the methot not work right, replace is done after calling the method, anyway thanks for your time